# DataGrid comboBoxItems acting weird

Tags: wpf, combobox, wpfdatagrid

I have a `DataGrid` with the following template

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Priority" Width="60" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox x:Name="comboPriority" SelectionChanged="DataGridComboBoxSelectionChanged" FontWeight="Bold" Loaded="comboPriority_Loaded">
                <ComboBoxItem Background="Red">
                    <Label Background="Red" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="40">A</Label>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Background="#FFFFC000">
                    <Label Background="#FFFFC000" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="40">B</Label>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Background="Yellow">
                    <Label Background="Yellow" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="40">C</Label>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Background="#FF92D050">
                    <Label Background="#FF92D050" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="40">D</Label>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Background="#FF00B0F0">
                    <Label Background="#FF00B0F0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="40">E</Label>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Background="#FFB1A0C7">
                    <Label Background="#FFB1A0C7" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="40">F </Label>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Background="#FFFF3399">
                    <Label Background="#FFFF3399" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="40">G</Label>
                </ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I can select an option, save it to the DB and see the selected values on initial load correctly. However, while I am scrolling, the selected values appear/disappear multiple times on other rows.

As an example. if I select a value from the first row's `ComboBox`, I see that value many times throughout the `DataGrid`.

I tried to refresh the grid right after drop-down selection but the `DataGrid` behaved the same.

Comment: What does the `comboPriority_Loaded` event handler do?

Comment: I set the selected value of ComboBoxes from the DB with it.

Comment: This is the cause of your issue. Don't do that. It seems that you're misunderstanding how the WPF datagrid works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the UI virtualization. You can disable it by setting the `VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing` attached property to `false`:

```
<DataGrid ... VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="False">
```

Beware that this may affect the scrolling performance negatively.

The best way to solve this would be to bind the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox` to a property of the type of the data objects that you populate the `DataGrid` with.